# requestLocationUpdates not happening automatically

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am currently creating an Android map application, where by I want the user to be able to track their own route. So basically they will press a start button, and then their current location will be detected, and as they start walking a polyline will be drawn dynamically.

At this moment I haven't drawn the polyline yet, but I am able to keep detecting the updated current location using mock locations. However to get the update I have to keep pressing the start button. Is there a way for the markers to appear on their own without me having to manually press the start button?

Here's my codes

**btnStart on click**

```
 btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // getting current location
            MyLocationListener myLocListener = new MyLocationListener();

            LocationManager locManager;
            String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
            locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(context);

            Criteria c = new Criteria();
            c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            c.setAltitudeRequired(false);
            c.setBearingRequired(false);
            c.setCostAllowed(true);
            c.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

            String provider = locManager.getBestProvider(c, true);
            Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 50, 10, myLocListener);

            LatLng currentPosition = updateWithNewLocation(loc);
            // getting current location - end


            // setting a marker at the curretnt location (start of polyline)
            Marker startLocation = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(currentPosition)
                    .title("Start Location")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPosition, 17));

        }
    });
```

**updateWithNewLocation method**

```
  private LatLng updateWithNewLocation(Location loc) {
    String latLonString;
    LatLng currentLocation = null;
    if (loc != null) {
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        double lon = loc.getLongitude();

        currentLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);

    } else {
        latLonString = "No location found";
    }

    return currentLocation;
}
```

last but not least, my **LocationListener**

```
 private final LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below ?

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 50, 10, myLocListener);
```

to

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, myLocListener);
```

Because you are requesting **50 metres** minimum to **update location** itself by **Location Manager**.

More details on [Location Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).

Hope it will help you.